# How to open a file the next time the Windows computer boots?

Tags: windows, boot

I'm going to be fixing a family friend's computer later and won't be interacting with the computer owner personally, so I would like to have a readme.txt to automatically open the first time (and only the first time) he boots the computer so he can see what I did to fix the problems and what he should avoid having these issues in the future. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: As a humorous side-note: your friend won't be reading it, so don't worry about it :)

Comment: Not just a txt file in the middile of his desktop called 'Read Me' or such? :)

Comment: You could place a ReadMe.txt including a few swearwords in the filename on the desktop. The swearwords will increase his curiousity heavily and he'll read it - trust me!

Answer (score 29):

Open the Registry Editor, and add the filename as string to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` when you are logged in as that specific user, or to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...` which opens that file for ány user.

Comment: This is the best way to accomplish this; the batch file approach suffers from a greater possibility of, say, an antivirus software freaking out and blocking it.

Comment: +1: Well, when the daily vote limit expires, I'll upvote this.  The batch file methods are so unneccessary. You can just put the document in the startupfolder/runonce and Windows will execute the associated program.

Comment: @Shinrai You're right, but can't eliminate the option anyways :P

Comment: @NGLN I forgot about that key, and agree that would probably be the better option

Comment: @Luke - I'm not disagreeing, just saying this is a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: I know, same here

Answer (score 13):

Just leave him a post-it note... or two. Assuming you leave one note for each problem you fix... I assume you'll end up like this:

[image: Just leave him a note]

Comment: haha, I like it, I may have to do that.

Answer (score 9):

Make a .BAT file in his Startup folder

```
@echo off
start /w notepad.exe C:\Path\To\filename.txt
del C:\Path\To\this_bat_file.bat
```

Just rename **filename.txt** and **this_bat_file.bat** to the proper names

Comment: Looks like it should do exactly what I need, I'll give it a try tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Better to put the full path of the file(s).

Comment: You can put in full paths, that's true. That would help it out quite a bit

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this is a Windows machine, you could use [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178706) that is built into Windows.

Comment: This is actually a very good solution. The task schedule includes a method for indicating that a task should only run once. ElvisFan, would you mind editing your answer with a bit more info about how one would configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting - but why not just an email, so he can review it again if he likes?

Assuming you have your reasons, the method Luke mentions is a good one.  On Windows 7 the startup folder for a user is:

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Or you can try putting one in the default:

C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup (<-- may have to create directory)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question , you wants to give some useful information and guides for him.

So I prefer instead of showing one time you may request him to save that document for his future reference.

So write the document and store it in some folder and put the shortcut link on Startup folder(Start->All Programs).

In the end of the document ask him to to remove the shortcut link.